# Need for a member function in a program

Tags: c++

In the [following program](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/85-constructors/#crayon-5b5c98d1f40cc902206652):

```
#include <iostream.h>

class Fraction
{
private:
    int m_numerator;
    int m_denominator;

public:
    Fraction() // default constructor
    {
        m_numerator = 0;
        m_denominator = 1;
    }

    int getNumerator() { return m_numerator; }
    int getDenominator() { return m_denominator; }
    double getValue() { return static_cast<double>(m_numerator) / m_denominator; }
};

int main()
{
    Fraction frac; // Since no arguments, calls Fraction() default constructor
    std::cout << frac.getNumerator() << "/" << frac.getDenominator() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I couldn’t understand the role of the function double getValue(). In the main function , we ask the compiler to call the functions getNumerator and getDenominator which directly pass the value of the variables m_numerator and m_denominator to the main function . The main function directly shows then in fractional form. Is there an explicit reason for the need of the function getValue ?

source : learncpp.com

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you copy & paste the code into the question as text please? It will end up formatted better than the screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of your code. Instead, copy your code into the question and [format it as a code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/9254539). It's both faster for you and it makes life easier for us since we can test out the code ourselves. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: "Is there an explicit reason for the need of the function getValue ?" - not in this example of just printing the numerator and denominator, no. But you can see why it might be useful for other numeric calculations using this class can't you?

Comment: @Rup ohh thanks for answering . I was confused about that because I’m just learning C++ and I thought that the program would only print thevalues in a fractional format .

Comment: I’m sorry I’m really new here so it’ll take some time for me to format the code . I need to learn that as well

Comment: @Rup thank you for formatting it ! I was trying to learn how to do just that

Comment: You shouldn't include standard library `.h` files directly in your programs. Instead, use stuff like `#include <iostream> //not iostream.h` and `#include <cmath> //not math.h`.

Comment: @FeiXiang thanks for the suggestion. I’m however not the person who’s written this . It’s from this website called learncpp where I’m learning c ++. I’ll try to follow this suggestion in the future .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We often try to make code generic so that we can reuse the code instead of writing new code similar to something we've already written. There isn't a use for the `getValue()` function in this program, but in other programs, it would be useful to have this function to return the value as a double so that we don't have to write the cast and the division (and maybe even checking for division by zero) over and over again all the time.

Comment: Okay I get the reason now. Thank you for helping ! I am new here so it’ll take sometime for me to learn how to format.